# How to get json from GraphQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

Hi I'm making a bridge that translates GraphQL's otherwise query to another service. I had the idea to take json from a query to GraphQL and make the query via resttemplate. But I couldn't find a way to take the request body.
I will be glad to see an example of your code or another more competent solution.

STACK: Spring boot+ java 8 + graphql

```
@Component
public class VehicleQuery implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleService vehicleService;

    public List<Vehicle> getVehicles(final int count) {
        return this.vehicleService.getAllVehicles(count);
    }

    public Optional<Vehicle> getVehicle(final int id) {
        return this.vehicleService.getVehicle(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a **JsonObject** instance. Add your query to the property. Add variables to the same object.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("query", query);
jsonObject.add("variables", variables);
```

Call the query in your java code like this:

```
HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = post(jsonObject.toString());
```

Comment: I can`t get query from request(

Comment: What do you have as input? Could you put it here or give an example? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I have Springboot + graphql and this create virtual controller and controller put this in query resolver. But i don`t know how i can get query.
I update decription  with my queryResolver

Comment: Can't you create the query looking at the Vehicle POJO? You'll need the query to get response

Comment: You can get the query and variables using the `DataFetchingEnvironment`.